# In Firefox, how to increase the height of the url bar while suggestions are displayed?

Tags: firefox

I'm using a large monitor (native resolution 1920 * 1080) and Firefox for browsing the web. I wonder whether it's possible to adjust the height of the URL bar when suggestions are displayed.

To clarify what I mean, I'm adding a screenshot:

[image: Firefox URL bar suggestions box too small]

Is there a simple way to tweak this behavior? I tried looking through the `about:config` page but couldn't find anything related. Preferably, I would like to adjust the height of the suggestion box to just fill the entire screen vertically and only if *that* isn't sufficient, a scroll bar should even appear.

If it takes an addon to do this, I'm willing to try it. But if it's doable without, that's even better.

Any suggestions?

Comment: unless someone has made a plug in for that in the addon section, i would say no.

Comment: Oh bummer. It seems that when Firefox was originally developed close to no one owned large monitors as many users to today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
about:config
```

`browser.urlbar.maxRichResults` set to whatever fits your screen